# No instance of overloaded function ".erase" matches the argument list

Tags: c++, vector

The error is "No Instance of overloaded function ... matches the argument list"
I understand that i give wrong argument to the erase function, but i do not know 
how to fix that

```
    void Folder::DeleteFolder(Folder* folder)
    {
     for(int i = 0; i> (this->Folder::GetFolders().size());i++)
     {
          if(this->Folder::GetFolders()[i]==folder)
          {
             //The problem occures on the next line
             this->Folder::GetFolders().erase(this->Folder::GetFolders()[i]);
             break;
          }
     } 
    }

   //here is the method GetFolders
   std::vector<Folder*>& Folder::GetFolders()
   {
     return this->listOfFolders;
   }
```

Comment: A hint: `erase()` expects a `std::vector<Folder*>::iterator`!

Comment: Have a look at the [*erase-remove idiom*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom).

Comment: I tried the erase-remove idiom of juanchopanza and it worked. Thank you all for the quick answers

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

You can simply use:

```
     std::vector<Folder*>::iterator itr= listOfFolders.begin();
     while( itr != listOfFolders.end())
     {
       if(*itr==folder){
          listOfFolders.erase( itr );
          break;
       }
       ++itr;
     }
```

Comment: AFAIK class std::vector has no member function find.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, you r right. this is the result of using Qt containers for long time. I have edited my code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all I think that you mean comparison of the object pointed to by folder with objects in tthe vector.

The general approach to do the task is by using standard algorithm `std::find_if` The code will look the following way

```
void Folder::DeleteFolder(Folder* folder)
{
    std::vector<Folder*> &v =  this->Folder::GetFolders();

    auto it = std::find_if( v.begin(), v.end(),
                            [&]( Folder *f ) { return ( *f == *folder ); } );

    if ( it != v.end() ) v.erase( it );
}
```